# Is it possible to install an old GNOME 3 version on Ubuntu 20.04 or any other up-to-date distro?

Tags: gnome, downgrade

This question may sound stupid, but I'm not to blame due to lack of experience with Linux.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 for around 3 months and got really fed up with the mediocre flat GNOME 3.36 UI. Around 5-6 years ago I had Ubuntu GNOME 14.04 installed and I loved the more skeuomorphic old GNOME interface (that was version 3.12 or 3.14 as far as I recall). For many reasons I was forced to move back to Windows 8.1, so it wasn't used for a long time.

How can I downgrade? Is it even possible to? If not, can I at least theme it like GNOME 3.14?

If changing the distro is mandatory, I can do that without a hassle. I was thinking about moving to Debian or Deepin anyway.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Found this screenshot, which is my expectation.

[GNOME 3.14](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOPf4.jpg)

Comment: Have a look at Budgie. It is an official Ubuntu release with classic layout

Comment: Looks nice indeed. If this question doesn't get answered, I'm definitely moving to Ubuntu Budgie.

Comment: What is more "skeuomorphic" in your screenshot over current versions? It is probably only the icons, so it is just a matter of finding and installing a different icon pack.

Comment: It's not only about the icons, man. The whole theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your packaged version of Gnome Desktop is compiled to match the rest of your system's versions. Attempting to switch Gnome Desktop versions is not recommended, and may break your system.

Experts who can compile the entire Gnome Desktop from source can obviously install whatever they like.

Comment: Dayum. That's disappointing. I'd pay such an expert 20 dollars to compile a Debian 10 ISO with GNOME 3.14 for me. Well, then Ubuntu Budgie, here I come!

Comment: $20 would be insulting to the fellows I know who could do it. With downloading the source, deconflicting the dependencies, compiling, testing, burning, and re-testing, you're looking at a minimum 4-hour job, at around $150/hr. Or you could learn to roll it yourself in about a week for free.

Comment: Oh, it's that complicated? Then I can give a whole 400-dollar! Anyway, that won't happen anyway, I was only expressing a random thought. Maybe I'll even consider into learning that.